# Different offset for different sections in scrollify plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I am using jQuery scrollify plugin on my website. It works great but I need to have custom offset for different areas of the page. For example all my **section** elements should have an offset of -200 while 2 **footer** elements should have an offset of -100px and -50px. This can't be achieved just by using interstitialSection. Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

**HTML**

```
<header>
    ....
</header>
<section>
</section>
....
//removed for brevity
....
<footer class="contact">
</footer>
<footer class="social-footer">
</footer>
```

**JS**

```
$.scrollify({
    section: "header, section, footer",
    interstitialSection: "header, section, .contact, .social-footer", 
    offset: -200,
    //this doesn't seem to work
    before: function (indexPosition, snapToElm) {
        if (indexPosition === 1) {
            snapToElm[indexPosition].css({ "margin-top": "200px" });
        } else if (indexPosition === 2) {
            snapToElm[indexPosition].css({ "margin-top": "100px" });
        } else if (indexPosition === 3) {
            snapToElm[indexPosition].css({ "margin-top": "150px" });
        }
    },
    afterRender: function () {
        //Picked up from another source 
        //set the first element initially to the desired offset
        $($(this.section)[0]).css({ "margin-top": "200px" });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `$.scrollify.setOptions()` method to change the offset per section.

Comment: I tryed to use setOptions to update visibility of scrollbar and it doesn't work. It simply does anything. I wrote this :$.scrollify.setOptions({scrollbars: false}) even in console, and nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

@Luke_Haass said that you have to use `$.scrollify.setOptions()`. I was reading the documentation and with `.setOptions()` method you can update the current scrollify options so try something like this. With `before` you can get the index of your next section that is going to change so in your `if (indexPosition === section)` use the `$.scrollify.setOptions()` to set a new options with your new offset!

```
var scrollifyOptions = {
        section: ".scroll , .scrollfull",
        sectionName: "section-name",
        interstitialSection: ".inters",
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        scrollSpeed: 1500,
        offset: scrolloff,
        scrollbars: true,
        standardScrollElements: "",
        setHeights: false,
        overflowScroll: true,
        updateHash: true,
        touchScroll: true,
        before: function (index, sections) {
            if (index == 1) {
                scrollifyOptions.offset = 0;
                $.scrollify.setOptions(scrollifyOptions);
            }
            else if (index == 2) {
                scrollifyOptions.offset = -50;
                $.scrollify.setOptions(scrollifyOptions);
            }
        },
        after: function () { },
        afterResize: function () { },
        afterRender: function () { },
        offsets: function () { }
    }
    $.scrollify(scrollifyOptions)
```

i hope this helps!